# Parsing a file with python to get a CSV

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a file of lines made as follows:

`{u'af': 4, **[a lots of attribute i don't need]**, u'prb_id': **6092**, u'result': [{u'result': [{u'rtt': 0.266, u'ttl': 255, u'from': u'**208.80.155.67**', u'size': 28}, {u'rtt': 0.413, u'ttl': 255, u'from': u'208.80.155.67', u'size': 28}, {u'rtt': 1.565, u'ttl': 255, u'from': u'208.80.155.67', u'size': 28}], u'hop': 1}, {u'result': [{u'rtt': 68.468, u'ttl': 254, u'from': u'**206.126.237.239**', u'size': 68}, {u'rtt': 67.844, u'ttl': 254, u'from': u'206.126.237.239', u'size': 68}, {u'rtt': 70.378, u'ttl': 254, u'from': u'206.126.237.239', u'size': 68}], u'hop': 2}[**a lots of attribute i don't need**]}`

I tried to parse it as a `JSON` file with:

```
data = []
with open('prova1') as f:
    for line in f:
    data.append(json.loads(line))
```

But I get the following `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

What I need is to take the values `prb_id` and every value in from field avoiding duplicates.

My goal is to get a CSV file with the following format:

```
6092,208.80.155.67,206.126.237.239
```

How can I parse it using Python?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a more complete file example. 
The reason for the error is most likely that your file is not formatted like JSON and you can therefore not parse it like that.

Comment: Each line is to long to paste it here.  
http://pastebin.com/Bqk5h7hd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not JSON (*), so the json module cannot decode it. But it looks like Python syntax, so `ast.literal_eval` could do a good job with it, but you will lose the order of fields:

```
data = []
with open('prova1') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(ast.literal_eval(line))
```

If you later want to extract **all** `from` fields, and as you structure can contain nested dictionnaries and lists, you could extract them recursively with:

```
def parse_for_key(m, id, k):
""" m is the dictionnary to parse, k the key for the id, k the key to extract"""
    def _do_parse(m, k, l): # recursive function passing the list being computed
        if isinstance(m, list): # process for a list
            for elt in m:       # recurse in all elements from the list
                _do_parse(elt, k, l) 
        elif isinstance(m, dict):   # process for a dictionnary
            if (k in m) and not (m[k] in l):   # evt. add value for key  if not already there
                l.append(m[k])
            for elt in m.values():
                _do_parse(elt, k, l)  # and recurse in values
        return l   # return the list
    return _do_parse(m, k, [m[id]])
```

You can then use `parse_for_key(m, 'prb_id', 'from')` where m is the result of the `litteral_eval` of one line and will get something like:

```
[6026, '83.212.7.42', '83.212.7.41', '62.217.100.63', '83.97.88.69', '62.40.112.165', ...]
```

---

(*) JSON requires identifiers to be enclosed in **double** quotes (`"`), and has no notion of the `u` prefix for unicode strings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is json parser expects objects' keys to be strings and string doesn't include unicode prefix in Json spec (see http://www.json.org/json-en.html)

I don't know any method to get json parse unicode prefix correctly.

Are thoses `**` in your real data ? If not you can still use this dirty trick (i'm not sure it will work for all cases) :

```
import json

s = """{u'a': 1, u'l':[u'b', u'c']}"""
exec("d = {}".format(s))

print(d)
print(json.dumps(d))
```

Outputs :

> {u'a': 1, u'l': [u'b', u'c']}
>
> {"a": 1, "l": ["b", "c"]}

The best way is of course to get a well formatted json as input, but i suppose you cannot have that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not proper JSON, it is the format Python uses to print dictionaries, but it is not valid JSON. For instance, JSON requires double quotes, not single quotes, and JSON does not allow `u"string"` to define a string.

Option 1: transform the string to json (to convince oneself that this is the root of the error):

```
$ cat ttt.json
{u'af': 4, u'prb_id': 6092, u'result': [{u'result': [{u'rtt': 0.266, u'ttl': 255, u'from': u'208.80.155.67', u'size': 28}, {u'rtt': 0.413, u'ttl': 255, u'from': u'208.80.155.67', u'size': 28}, {u'rtt': 1.565, u'ttl': 255, u'from': u'208.80.155.67', u'size': 28}], u'hop': 1}, {u'result': [{u'rtt': 68.468, u'ttl': 254, u'from': u'206.126.237.239', u'size': 68}, {u'rtt': 67.844, u'ttl': 254, u'from': u'206.126.237.239', u'size': 68}, {u'rtt': 70.378, u'ttl': 254, u'from': u'206.126.237.239', u'size': 68}], u'hop': 2}]}
>>> import json
>>> a = open("ttt.json").read()
>>> json.loads(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/[...]__init__.py", line 309, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "/usr/local/[...]decoder.py", line 351, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "/usr/local/[...]decoder.py", line 367, in raw_decode
        obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
>>> # But after some replacements,
>>> json.loads(json.loads(re.sub("u'([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*)'", r'"\1"', a)))
    {'prb_id': 6092, 'result': [{'result': [{'rtt': 0.266, 'size': 28, 'from': '208.80.155.67', 'ttl': 255}, {'rtt': 0.413, 'size': 28, 'from': '208.80.155.67', 'ttl': 255}, {'rtt': 1.565, 'size': 28, 'from': '208.80.155.67', 'ttl': 255}], 'hop': 1}, {'result': [{'rtt': 68.468, 'size': 68, 'from': '206.126.237.239', 'ttl': 254}, {'rtt': 67.844, 'size': 68, 'from': '206.126.237.239', 'ttl': 254}, {'rtt': 70.378, 'size': 68, 'from': '206.126.237.239', 'ttl': 254}], 'hop': 2}], 'af': 4}
```

Option two (this is the preferred option): use `ast` to read the string:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
{'prb_id': 6092, 'result': [{'result': [{'rtt': 0.266, 'size': 28, 'from': '208.80.155.67', 'ttl': 255}, {'rtt': 0.413, 'size': 28, 'from': '208.80.155.67', 'ttl': 255}, {'rtt': 1.565, 'size': 28, 'from': '208.80.155.67', 'ttl': 255}], 'hop': 1}, {'result': [{'rtt': 68.468, 'size': 68, 'from': '206.126.237.239', 'ttl': 254}, {'rtt': 67.844, 'size': 68, 'from': '206.126.237.239', 'ttl': 254}, {'rtt': 70.378, 'size': 68, 'from': '206.126.237.239', 'ttl': 254}], 'hop': 2}], 'af': 4}
>>>
```

Comment: Hoping there is no string ending with `u` or including a `"` in this file (with option 1)

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` should be able to handle `u`-prefixed strings without any problem. It _is_ designed to handle Python literals, after all.

Comment: @Chris hum indeed, a first test I made failed, but I re-tried as you confirmed my intuition and it succeeded. Not sure what happened

Comment: @C.LECLERC yes you are right. Changed to use regexp